# ENTITY FRAMEWORK - fazer uma consulta tipo like do SQL

Tags: entity-framework

Fala Pessoal,

Estou com um problema que pode ser não esteja fazendo corretamente, tenho uma consulta em um campo descrição de uma tabela por exemplo

> Select descricao tabela where campo like 'teste%descricao'

Como faço essa pesquisa com entity framework? pois se eu utilizo no termo o `Contains`, ele faria +/- como `like '%teste descricao%'`, mas não é isso que quero.

```
  Context.Item.Where(c=> c.descricao.Contains(termo)).toList();
```

Obrigado pela Ajuda

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho como testar aqui, mas acredito que pode ficar assim:

Considerando que você queira a sintaxe para o mesmo resultado de `like 'teste%descricao'`:

```
Context.Item.Where(c=> c.descricao.StartsWith("teste") && c.descricao.EndsWith("descricao")).toList();
```

Comment: O problema é se eu tiver um termo maior por exemplo TV Led 40 , acho que vou ter utilizar o sqlQuery do entity framework....

Comment: não entendi a questão do termo maior...rs

Comment: Desculpa, um termo maior que 2 palavras 3 quatro etc...cada termo teria que ter um coringa '%'

Comment: há um problema com o que você está querendo, porque `like 'teste%descricao'` é diferente de `like 'teste%' or like '%descricao'` qual sua real necessidade ? @AlexBecker

Comment: Ola Rovann, tenho um campo de pesquisa que deve pesquisar pelos termos informados na base desta forma : ex. "teste descricao de qualquer coisa" like 'teste%descricao%de%qualquer%coisa' queria uma forma de fazer isso pelo entity framework mas parece um pouco complexo, a melhor forma de utilizar creio que seja fazer a pesquisa com o sqlQuery.... não estou vendo outro jeito....

Comment: é exatamente sobre isso: `'teste%descricao%de%qualquer%coisa'` que eu coloquei no comentário acima. isso não faz muito sentido, é isso mesmo que você quer ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o StartWith, que seria como Like 'Teste%' ou o EndWith, que seria como Like '%Teste'.  Segue exemplo:

```
Context.Item.Where(c=> c.descricao.StartsWith(termo)).toList();

Context.Item.Where(c=> c.descricao.EndsWith(termo)).toList();
```

Comment: Cara sim o problema é que o termo pode ter mais parametros, por exemplo 'televisão led 40'